# Angular subrouting, nested router-outlets

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 4 app with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) tabs, and I am trying to use tabbed subrouting.

I have defined some routes in my main routing file:

```
...
{ path: 'wall', component: WallHandlerComponent, canActivate: [LoggedGuard], children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'recent', outlet: 'walloutlet' },
    { path: 'recent', component: RecentEventsComponent, outlet: 'walloutlet' },
    { path: 'ranking', component: RankingUsersComponent, outlet: 'walloutlet' }
] },
...
```

I load `WallHandlerComponent` in my main `<router-outlet>` with no problem.

Now, inside my `wall-handler.component.html` file I have a secondary/named `<router-outlet>`:

```
...
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
    <a md-tab-link
        *ngFor="let link of wallNavLinks"
        [routerLink]="link.path"
        routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla.isActive">
        {{link.label}}
    </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet name="walloutlet"></router-outlet>
...
```

And in my `wall-handler.component.ts`, I define `wallNavLinks` as follows:

```
...
get wallNavLinks(): { label: string, path: any[] }[] {
    return [
        { label: 'Recent', path: [{ outlets: { walloutlet: 'recent' } }] },
        { label: 'Ranking', path: [{ outlets: { walloutlet: 'ranking' } }] }
    ];
}
...
```

However, when I load `/wall`, instead of loading anything inside secondary (`walloutlet`) outlet, browser just goes crazy and hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not so sure about your wallNavLinks but can you try this
`{ label: 'Recent', path: './recent'}`,
`{ label: 'Ranking', path: './ranking'}`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner without the name of the `router-outlet`?

Comment: Use outlet name as well.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner not working. As per Angular example (https://angular.io/guide/router#add-a-secondary-route), routing to named outlets should be specified as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. The only difference I notice is in angular example, they defined their route within square brackets. So can you try this
`{ label: 'Recent', path: [{ outlets: { walloutlet: ['recent'] } }] }`

Comment: Tried also, same result... v_v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the `outlet`-related details are not necessary at all:

Routing file:

```
...
{ path: 'wall', component: WallHandlerComponent, canActivate: [LoggedGuard], 
children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'recent', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'recent', component: RecentEventsComponent },
  { path: 'ranking', component: RankingUsersComponent }
] },
...
```

HTML file:

```
...
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of wallNavLinks"
    [routerLink]="link.path"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet name="walloutlet"></router-outlet>
...
```

Typescript file:

```
...
get wallNavLinks(): { label: string, path: string }[] {
  return [
    { label: 'Recent', path: 'recent' },
    { label: 'Ranking', path: 'ranking' }
  ];
}
...
```

Output seems to be automatically going to the right `<router-outlet>` because it is already located in the component specified to have children components by the routing file.

Comment: i had to remove the name of the sub-outlet to get it working